# XPath: select text node

Tags: xml, xpath, selection

Having the following XML:

```
<node>Text1<subnode/>text2</node>
```

How do I select either the first or the second text node via XPath?

Something like this:

```
/node/text()[2]
```

of course doesn't work because it's the merged result of every text inside the node.

Comment: You wrote: *`/node/text()[2]` [...] doesn't work because it's the merged result of every text inside the node* That's wrong: it means *second text node child of `node` root element*. The **string value** (concatenation of descendant text nodes) would be `string(/node)`

Comment: You mean that Xpath query should work? Well, I guess I have another problem somewhere else then. ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 221, accepted):

> Having the following XML:
>
> ```
> <node>Text1<subnode/>text2</node>
> ```
>
> How do I select either the first or
>   the second text node via XPath?

**Use**:

```
/node/text()
```

This selects all text-node children of the top element (named "node") of the XML document.

```
/node/text()[1]
```

This selects the first text-node child of the top element (named "node") of the XML document.

```
/node/text()[2]
```

This selects the second text-node child of the top element (named "node") of the XML document.

```
/node/text()[someInteger]
```

This selects the someInteger-th text-node child of the top element (named "node") of the XML document. It is equivalent to the following XPath expression:

```
/node/text()[position() = someInteger]
```

Comment: Does this work in PHP? I'm trying to loop through only text nodes, even those in-between a set of tags. The problem is that is smashing the content of multiple text nodes together, regardless of tags. Using `//*[text()]` anyway. `/html/text()` does not work.

Comment: @AaronGillion, Yes, AFAIK PHP has a correctly working XPath 1.0 evaluation. Do note that `/html/text()` doesn't select all text nodes in the document -- only the text nodes that are children (not descendents) of the top, `html` element. You probably want `/html//text()`  .  Some knowledge and understanding of XPath is typically required in order to construct XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the double-slash trick a little bit ago!

Answer (score 31):

your xpath should work . i have tested your xpath and mine in both MarkLogic and Zorba Xquery/ Xpath implementation.

Both should work.

```
/node/child::text()[1] - should return Text1
/node/child::text()[2] - should return text2


/node/text()[1] - should return Text1
/node/text()[2] - should return text2
```