# Getting Project Version from Maven POM in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

Is there any way a Jenkins build can be aware of the Maven version number of a project after processing the POM?

I've got some projects where versioning is controlled by Maven, and in a post-build job we'd like to create a Debian package and call some shell scripts. What I need is for the version number that Maven used to be available as a Jenkins environment variable so I can pass it to post-build actions.

To be clear, I'm *not* needing to know how to get Jenkins to pass a version number to Maven; instead I want Maven to pass a version number to Jenkins!

Comment: Just a suggestion: what about this: http://mojo.codehaus.org/deb-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a lot of digging around (I never realised how poorly-documented Jenkins is!) I found a quite trivial solution.

1. Install the Groovy plugin
2. Add a `Post Step` to your Maven build of type `Execute **system** Groovy script`
3. Paste in the following snippet of Groovy:

**Script:**

```
import hudson.model.*;
import hudson.util.*;

def thr = Thread.currentThread();
def currentBuild = thr?.executable;
def mavenVer = currentBuild.getParent().getModules().toArray()[0].getVersion();
def newParamAction = new hudson.model.ParametersAction(new hudson.model.StringParameterValue("MAVEN_VERSION", mavenVer));
currentBuild.addAction(newParamAction);
```

The build environment variable called `MAVEN_VERSION` will now be available for substitution into other post-build steps in the usual manner (`${MAVEN_VERSION}`). I'm using it for Git tagging amongst other things.

Comment: This works like a charm, if you update the `def mavenVer = ` line to what's in your [later followup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10205702/487663) - `def mavenVer = currentBuild.getParent().getModules().toArray()[0].getVersion();`

Comment: Works indeed when "def mavenVer..." is replaced with the code from the previous comment.

Comment: This has the same issue as `POM_VERSION`, due to this bug issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24869

Comment: This works only with SYSTEM Groovy Scripts to have access to Jenkins' JVM objects (like build execution and parameters action). However, executing in SYSTEM has one drawback : it will execute on master, meaning that if your build is executed on a slave, pom.xml won't be found since workspace resides on the slave and is not accessible from the master.

Answer (score 76):

You can use the ${POM_VERSION} variable, which was introduced with https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18272

Comment: Awesome!  Verify you need Jenkins maven plugin v2.3 or later for ` ${POM_VERSION}` to work and I think it needs to be a Maven project type.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Maven Interation plugin in Jenkins is version 2.5, still it says: ${ENV, var="POM_VERSION"}: bad substitution if I try to use this variable directly or via the above mentioned way. Unrecognized macro 'POM_VERSION' in '${POM_VERSION}.${BUILD_NUMBER}' during Build Number Set plugin box.

Comment: Keep in mind that POM_VERSION does not take into account any environment variables that may have been passed to the maven build process. For example: <version>${CUSTOM_VERSION}<version> will be empty or with default value.

Comment: POM_VERSION is cached incorrectly due to this bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24869

Answer (score 12):

As other answers already pointed out, if you are using the Maven project type, you have access to the **$POM_VERSION** variable.  But if you are not, you can use this sequence of steps (ugly but reliable).  Doing it this way relies on the same version of maven to determine the pom version (while handling complex parent/child pom inheritance where **<version>** may not even be present for the child).

1. **Maven step with this goal:**

   `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -l version.log`
2. **Shell step**: (You may need to adjust the path to version.log depending on your hierarchy)

   `echo "POM_VERSION=$(grep -v '\[' version.log)" > props.properties`
3. **Inject Environment Variables step** (Environment Injector Plugin):

   Properties File Path: `props.properties`

Now you can use **$POM_VERSION** as if this were a Maven project.

What this does: Uses maven to print out the version together with a mess of output, then greps out the mess of output leaving just the version, writes it to a file using properties file format and then injects it into the build environment.  The reason this is better than a one-liner like `mvn ..... | grep -v '\['` is that using a Maven step does not make assumptions about the installed maven versions and will be handled by the same auto-installation as any other maven steps.

Comment: One problem with the grep filter there: if you don't have the plugins in repository, you'll get also the "Downloading..." lines in POM_VERSION. E.g.: `+ echo 'POM_VERSION=Downloading: ...`

Comment: `echo "POM_VERSION=$(xmllint --xpath '/*[local-name()="project"]/*[local-name()="version"]/text()' pom.xml)" > props.properties` is an alternative way to get the POM. It's not portable, relies on xmllint.

Answer (score 9):

I used [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps) plugin in a declarative pipeline job to get Maven version. In the example below I use script variable instead of environment variable, because that can be modified and passed between stages.

```
def TAG_SELECTOR = "UNINTIALIZED"
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "mvn --batch-mode -U deploy"
                script {
                    TAG_SELECTOR = readMavenPom().getVersion()
                }
                echo("TAG_SELECTOR=${TAG_SELECTOR}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** You must approve the getVersion() method after creating the job in *Manage jenkins* > *In-process Script Approval*.

See also:

- [readMavenPom documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readmavenpom-code-read-a-maven-project-file)

Comment: Super simple, elegant and reliable! (Note that you don't need to use the full syntax `getVersion()` in Groovy, you can instead use simply `.version`.)

Comment: An administrator might need to [grant approval for the `readMavenPom().getVersion()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412951/545127)

Answer (score 3):

We used the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin).

```
    String regex = '.*\\[INFO\\] Building .+ (.+)';
    def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(regex);
    if (matcher == null) {
        version = null;
    } else {
        version =  matcher.group(1);
    }
```

Adding this to Jenkins for use later is a bit tricky.  Give this a shot, although I remember this causing us some headaches. (Sorry, we did this a long time ago)

```
def addBuildParameter(String key, String value) {
    manager.build.addAction(new hudson.model.ParametersAction(new hudson.model.StringParameterValue(key,value))); 
}
```

Comment: How would you then make `version` available to other things steps in the job?

Comment: hi deejay, I expanded the answer a bit.  Good luck!

Comment: This solution works best for cases where you have a dynamically populated version number in the POM file using variables. Using POM_VERSION or parsing the pom.xml file would not work in those cases.

Comment: Have a way iterate like: while(matcher.find()) {}
?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same need and solved as suggested with Groovy parsing the pom.

```
import jenkins.util.*;
import jenkins.model.*;

def thr = Thread.currentThread();
def currentBuild = thr?.executable;
def workspace = currentBuild.getModuleRoot().absolutize().toString();

def project = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("$workspace/pom.xml"))

def param = new hudson.model.StringParameterValue("project.version", project.version.toString())
currentBuild.addAction(new hudson.model.ParametersAction(param));
```

Add this script as a post step of type "Execute system Groovy script" (so it's not needed to install Groovy) and paste the code in the "Groovy command".

Comment: See [project-version-from-maven-to-sonar-using-hudson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691818/project-version-from-maven-to-sonar-using-hudson/15879456#15879456)

Comment: I've tried to use `${project.version}` in the shell script step after that and it failed: `bad substituion`, after I've renamed `project.version` to `project_version` - it worked. Seems jenkins don't allow `dot` in var names?

Comment: This does not seem to work in Jenkins 2.46+.  Although Groovy extracts the version fine, the `project.version` environment variable is empty in the rest of my Freestyle project.  Is there something that changed in Jenkins 2+ that would make this obsolete?  I'm trying to access the var subsequently as `${project.version}`

Answer (score 3):

Execute the Maven Plugin "exec-maven-plugin" in "Execute Shell" as a "Conditional step" worked for me:

```
mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${projects.version}' --non-recursive org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec
```

Integrate in Jenkins:

```
-> "Add post-build step"
    -> "Conditional steps (single or multiple)"
        -> "Execute Shell:"
```

> export MY_POM_VERSION=`mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo"
>   -Dexec.args='${projects.version}' --non-recursive org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec` && [[
>   "${MY_POM_VERSION}" == "THE_VERSION_TO_BE_MATCHED" ]] && echo
>   "CONDITION_IS_MET"

```
    -> "Steps to run if condition is met"
        -> Add any build step you need
```

Notes:

- THE_VERSION_TO_BE_MATCHED has to exchanged with your version
- '&& echo "CONDITION_IS_MET"' is only for debugging purposes. For the same purpose you can add a '&& echo "MY_POM_VERSION=${MY_POM_VERSION}"' after the mvn command in order to understand what's going on.

This approach is more reliable than a "grep" and it could be an alternative if the Jenkins Ruby Plugin is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do :

```
MAVEN_VERSION=`grep A -2 -B 2 "<your_project_name>" pom.xml | grep version | cut -d\> -f 2 | cut -d\< -f 1`-commit-"`echo $GIT_COMMIT`"
```

Explanation:  assuming that you have your project name within a line or two above/below version like a normal pom:

```
<groupId>org.apache.bigtop</groupId>
<artifactId>bigpetstore</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Then you can easily grep for the artifactId, use the "before/after" grep actions to suck in the version with it, and then grep the version out and use the simple unix "cut" command to splice out the content between "version" tags.

I like the Jenkins-groovy integration, but this is alot easier and will work even on a build server which you dont have control over (i.e. because bash is universal).

Comment: This worked like a charm but fetched multiple version-infos, because auf the dependencies which also contain a version-tag.
Adding a head before the grep and pipe it worked for me

    MAVEN_VERSION=`head "<your_project_name>" pom.xml | grep A -2 -B 2  | grep version | cut -d\> -f 2 | cut -d\< -f 1`-commit-"`echo $GIT_COMMIT`"

Comment: @JoeDred I still get multiply versions. But my "another version" is not from dependencies, but from properties: **<groupId>cz.px.iis</groupId>
 <artifactId>iis-core-ng</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>2.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <properties>
  <vaadin-version>7.7.5</vaadin-version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> 
 </properties>** and output is __2.1.1-SNAPSHOT 7.7.5__

Comment: @agad Maybe you should limit the lines you pipe to the first grep. Head takes an optional argument -n or --lines. Try **head --help** which shows how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
POM_VERSION=$( \
    xmlstarlet sel \
    -N x='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0' \
    -t \
    -v '//x:project/x:version/text()' \
    pom.xml \
)
```

**Explanation:**

You can do this in a one-liner using a command-line XPath tool, such as those mentioned at "[How to execute XPath one-liners from shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell)".  I chose [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), but they all have similar syntax.

When parsing a POM, you have to account for namespaces.  The docs [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html) helped me figure this out.

In order to get the text for an element in XPath, you use the text() function as explained at [XPath: select text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033955/xpath-select-text-node).

My POM looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

The downside here is that if the namespace changes, you have to change the command.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'Execute System Groovy Script' as follows:

```
import jenkins.util.*;
import jenkins.model.*;

def thr = Thread.currentThread();
def currentBuild = thr?.executable;
def projectManager = build.getProject()
def file = projectManager.getWorkspace().child("pom.xml");
def project = new XmlSlurper().parseText(file.readToString())

def param = new hudson.model.StringParameterValue("currentVersion", project.version.toString())
currentBuild.addAction(new hudson.model.ParametersAction(param));
```

By using Execute System Groovy script you have direct access to the build, from which you can get the project and thus the "child" file in this case pom.xml.

You won't have to create a new file and as you can see it offers very powerful access to every file within the workspace.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Akom`s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35184962/6805478) the pre steps to have POM_VERSION are:

1. "Inject environment variables" with property
   file your_property_file. Note if you select "Inject environment variables to the build process" the file needs to exist in the jenkins workspace.
2. run in a pre step execute shell the follwing
   bash script.

Script

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -l project_version
# grep for the version pattern rather than not mentioning '\['
echo "POM_VERSION=$(grep -E  '^[0-9.]+(-SNAPSHOT)?$' project_version)" > your_property_file
```