# Jenkins - MavenBuild.getMavenArtifacts() Returns Null

Tags: maven, groovy, hudson, jenkins

Since Jenkins 1.460, calling `getMavenArtifacts()` on an instance of `MavenBuild` is returning null, whereas previously that would work fine.

Have there been breaking changes in the Jenkins API, or is this a Jenkins bug?

The code I'm executing is a post-build System Groovy script, that exposes the Maven version of a build as an environment variable for subsequent steps in the Jenkins build process to use:

```
import hudson.model.*;
import hudson.util.*;

def thr = Thread.currentThread();
def currentBuild = thr?.executable;
def mavenVer = currentBuild.getMavenArtifacts().getModuleRecords()[0].mainArtifact.version;
def newParamAction = new hudson.model.ParametersAction(new hudson.model.StringParameterValue("MAVEN_VERSION", mavenVer));
currentBuild.addAction(newParamAction);
```

Comment: There definitely have been [changes to Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commits/jenkins-1.460/maven-plugin) for 1.460 . If rolling Jenkins back to a previous version is not an option, consider pinning just the plugin to the previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround, although I don't know why an unannounced breaking change was made to the API - hopefully it's a bug that will get fixed.

Substitute:

```
def mavenVer = currentBuild.getMavenArtifacts().getModuleRecords()[0].mainArtifact.version;
```

for

```
def mavenVer = currentBuild.getParent().getModules().toArray()[0].getVersion();
```

Comment: Hey I'm getting exception with this and I'm on jenkins 1.625.3.2  =>                                                 ERROR: Build step failed with exception
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.getModules() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getModuleRoot(), getModuleRoots(), getBuilds(), getWidgets()