# How do I Extract Version ID from POM inside Jenkins Declarative and Scripted pipelines?

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've created a pipeline and using the embedded groovy pipeline script definition and can't seem to get the version ID of the project from the POM. I tried this which works in a groovy console but on in the Jenkins build pipeline script:

```
def project = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("pom.xml"))
def pomv = project.version.toString()
```

According to the documentation Jenkins has a `$POM_VERSION` but the value doesn't have anything in it when I assign it to a variable and echo it out.

```
def pomv = "$POM_VERSION"
```

OR

```
def pomv = '$POM_VERSION"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Project Version from Maven POM in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893503/getting-project-version-from-maven-pom-in-jenkins)

Comment: @user301693 can you accept my answer? This post has been here for a long time and still there are no answers accepted.

Answer (score 87):

Use [`readMavenPom`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/) like this:

```
pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
pom.version
```

See [Model](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/) reference for properties (like the above version).

For this to work, one has to install [Pipeline Utility Steps plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Utility+Steps+Plugin)

Comment: This works... Need to install the Pipeline Utility plugin though for it to work

Comment: This function unfortunately doesn't work with maven feature like revision ( https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html ) and it's going to be deprated as well as write as writeMavenPom ( https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/pull/47/commits/eeebaa891a006c083ce10f883b7c1264533bb692 )

Comment: Even though it is marked deprecated, I prefer it to calling `mvn help:evaluate` for this because it is faster and does not require my `pom.xml` to be valid (because it references an internal parent POM which is unknown to Maven Central - and at the place where I read the version I do not have access to the necessary `settings.xml`).

Answer (score 30):

In Jenkins 2.138.3 there are two different types of pipelines.

Declarative and Scripted pipelines.

"Declarative pipelines is a new extension of the pipeline DSL (it is basically a pipeline script with only one step, a pipeline step with arguments (called directives), these directives should follow a specific syntax. The point of this new format is that it is more strict and therefore should be easier for those new to pipelines, allow for graphical editing and much more.
scripted pipelines is the fallback for advanced requirements."

[jenkins pipeline: agent vs node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050626/jenkins-pipeline-agent-vs-node)

Here is an example of a Declarative Pipeline:

```
pipeline {

    agent any


    environment {
    //Use Pipeline Utility Steps plugin to read information from pom.xml into env variables
    IMAGE = readMavenPom().getArtifactId()
    VERSION = readMavenPom().getVersion()
    }


    stages {

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "${VERSION}"
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Example of Scripted Pipeline

```
node('master') {

  stage('Test') {
    IMAGE = readMavenPom().getArtifactId()
    VERSION = readMavenPom().getVersion()
    echo "IMAGE: ${IMAGE}"
    echo "VERSION: ${VERSION}"
  }

}
```

Here are some good links:

Declarative 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/declarative-examples/jenkinsfile-examples/mavenDocker.groovy

Scripted
https://bulldogjob.com/articles/726-exploring-jenkins-pipelines-a-simple-delivery-flow

Comment: @user301693 it's been a while since this post has existed, can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 10):

You could always shell out and use maven to query the version, e.g. like so:

```
echo sh(returnStdout: true, 
        script: 'mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:evaluate ' +
                 '-Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout ' +
                 '--batch-mode -U -e -Dsurefire.useFile=false'
        ).trim()
# Note: Use "./mvnw" with Maven wrapper
```

Where

- `-Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout` are mandatory (see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html#forceStdout) for details), and
- `--batch-mode -U -e -Dsurefire.useFile=false`
  are recommended for CI usage (see [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/4af47ea76232588c01f3abac1677e22e09645d33/pipeline-examples/maven-and-jdk-specific-version/mavenAndJdkSpecificVersion.groovy#L5-L10) for details).

This is also implemented in the shared library [ces-build-lib](https://github.com/cloudogu/ces-build-lib/blob/5369637b49a61e4e59d7e9625b4ddd13b034befe/src/com/cloudogu/ces/cesbuildlib/Maven.groovy#L75). Here it is as convenient as

```
echo mvn.version
```

The [Getting Started with Pipeline](https://web.archive.org/web/20160903090604/https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) page showed yet another option. It has some disadvantages, though (see bellow and comments):

```
def version() {
    def matcher = readFile('pom.xml') =~ '<version>(.+?)</version>'
    matcher ? matcher[0][1] : null
}
```

This always matches the first `<version>` tag to be found in the `pom.xml`. This *should* be the version of the maven module or its parent in most cases. It could be the version of the parent, though.

Comment: If you depend on a parent POM, then use matcher[1][1], because matcher[0][1] matches the parent POM's version.

Comment: This answer doesn't work in any of my POMs, because there is always more than one <version> tag.

Comment: @Jolta thanks for the hint. I edited the post. Does this work for you now?

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee whatsoever that "the first <version> tag to be found in the pom.xml" is the artifact version. You'd be taking a large chance on the assumption that people are putting XML tags in a certain order, which is not at all required by the format. As you stated yourself, it's quite likely to be the parent artifact version instead, which might give completely wrong results. Parsing the XML seems like the only safe way to edit a POM.

Comment: Your first solution (calling sh(mvn... and capture the console out) worked out of the box for me. Thanks for the interesting mvn command line. Maybe you could elaborate a little bit why the used CLI options are needed. It's not obvious for me what "-U -e -Dsurefire.useFile=false" really does.

Comment: @Heri Done. Please add anything that you might find useful

Comment: Thanks. I think the further link explains everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `readMavenPom` function that is available.

More info is here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readmavenpom-read-a-maven-project-file

Comment: Note that you need to install the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin to get this step.

Comment: Pipeline Utility Steps plugin says it needs Pipeline: Groovy plugin 1.11 which is almost 2 years old and way behind the current 2.30 (or so). This makes me nervous.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the map to do this.

```
 def pomFile = readFile(pomName)
 def pom = new XmlParser().parseText(pomFile)
 def gavMap = [:]
 gavMap['groupId'] =  pom['groupId'].text().trim()
 gavMap['artifactId'] =  pom['artifactId'].text().trim()
 gavMap['version'] =  pom['version'].text().trim()
```

Comment: dont know why this was downvoted. this will allow you to get the first version and avoid parent version

Comment: In '21 this needs to be in a `script { }` block, and also requires the following approvals in <jenkinshost>/scriptApproval which introduces security problems;
`method groovy.util.NodeList text
method groovy.util.XmlParser parseText java.lang.String
new groovy.util.XmlParser
`, Nevertheless works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I've just enhanced @haridsv solution without using grep:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
def call(String mvnBin = 'mvn',String pom_file = 'pom.xml') {

return sh(
        script: mvnBin+''' -N -f '''+pom_file+''' org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout''',
        returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

You'd better not use readMavenPom since it's going to be deprecated ( see PR https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/pull/47/commits/eeebaa891a006c083ce10f883b7c1264533bb692 ). You can copy and paste this in a file such as evaluateMavenPomVersion.groovy :-)

Answer (score 1):

jenkins pipeline add this stage.
more [see](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readmavenpom-read-a-maven-project-file)

```
    stage('info')
    {
        steps
        {
            script
            {
                def version = sh script: 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true
                def artifactId = sh script: 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true
                
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `readMavenPom` is the most straight-forward answer, but since it required installation of an additional pipeline plugin, here is another that uses the native maven approach instead of loading xml (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3545363/95750))

```
def mvn_project_version(pom_file) {
    return sh(
        script: """mvn -N -f $pom_file org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version |
                   grep -Ev '(^\\s*\\[|Download\\w+:)'""",
        returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

Because of the use of `grep` command this may not work on some platforms that are not posix compatible, but you can always process the output in Groovy instead of piping through `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is the source of truth, use it directly.

For example, to get the value of property `foo.bar` from pom.xml in Jenkinsfile:

```
def bar = sh(script: 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=foo.bar -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true)
```

Also, [docs of Pipeline Utility Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readmavenpom-read-a-maven-project-file) suggest avoiding using `readMavenPom`.

> Avoid using this step and writeMavenPom. It is better to use the sh step to run mvn goals.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just starting with `Jenkisfile` and I had the same problem as you. Since `XmlSlurper` and `XmlParser` are forbidden by default configuration i have crated below function to extract maven version:

```
String readProjectVersion(String pom) {
    //Take value of the <project> tag
    def matcher = pom.trim() =~ /(?s)<project[^>]*>(.*)<\/project>/
    def pomWithoutProject = matcher[0][1].trim()

    //remove every tag except <version>, since only project version is not encapsulated in the other tag e.g. dependency, parent, plugin
    def nonVersionMatcher = pomWithoutProject =~ /(?s)\s*(?!<version>)<([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>\s*/
    def versionTag = nonVersionMatcher.replaceAll("").trim()
    //Take value of the <version> tag
    def versionTagMatcher = versionTag =~ /<version>(.*)<\/version>/
    if (versionTagMatcher.matches()) {
        return versionTagMatcher[0][1]
    }
    //no version tag, version should be inherited from parent version
    def parentVersionMatcher = pomWithoutProject =~ /(?s)\s*<parent>.*<version>(.*)<\/version>.*<\/parent>\s*/
    return parentVersionMatcher[0][1]
}
```

I have tested this solution against files where parent was declared, version was first statement, version was last statement and with presence of version in nested tags like `dependency`, `plugin` etc.