# permissive script security plugin not working in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Everytime a non-admin user in Jenkins makes some changes in Jenkins, the script changes has to be approved by a Jenkins admin. I am looking for a way to disable this and i found this plugin- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Permissive+Script+Security+Plugin

i have installed and enabled this plugin as mentioned in the page, and the plugin status shows enabled as well here `<jenkins-url>/systemInfo`and also jenkins process `ps -efH | grep Jenkins` shows the plugin status but my script changes(as non-admin user) still asks for admin approval.

Is there anyone here who has used  this plugin and can help me out with how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

The Permissive Script Security plugin only works with Whitelisting code in a sandbox, not with authorizing complete scripts. Enable the Groovy sandbox for the scripts to automatically approve, then it should work. This was made clear in a comment in a [bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47570?focusedCommentId=342795&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-342795).

If your script is a [Job DSL](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) script, then the Groovy sandbox should be enabled and job run as a specific user. For this the [Authorize Project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin) can be used. Just add a default build authorization which is not the "anonymous" user, or a setting for the specific projects. The Job DSL plugin only supports sandboxing when the job is run as a specific user.