# Groovy is not entring the If condition in Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy

I want to deploy only the changed files, So I have this script inside the jenkinsfile

```
 def ChangeStes(){
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
        for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
            def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
            for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
                def entry = entries[j]
                echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
                def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
                for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
                    def file = files[k]
                    echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
                    if (file.path.contains('functions/ec2-instances'))  {
                     // NEVER ENTERING HERE 
                    }
               }
            }
        }
 }
```

The build finishes everytime with success and it does not process the condition on the file path.

How to resolve this? I have many If conditions.

Comment: Are you sure the file path actually contains that fragment?

Comment: did you tried to put `println file.getPath()` before if? or additional variables as j,i,k for instance

Comment: the echo of the file path is right there ${file.path} and I tried also with if file.path @xxxvodnikxxx

Comment: @doelleri yes pretty sure, I show it with the echo

Comment: show the output of the line `echo "  ${file.editType.name} :: ${file.path} :: ${file.path.getClass()}"`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you should use containsAll function instead contains. See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.1/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#contains(java.lang.Object)