# Get property value from xml file in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile in which I need a property from my .csproj file (dotnet core project)

I have tried this:

`def versionPrefix =  sh(script: 'cat ./src/project.csproj | grep (?<=<VersionPrefix>).*(?=</VersionPrefix>)')`

I know I'm probably far off, so I'm not necessarily looking for something close to this, but I am looking for a solution not requiring plugins (preferably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution without pipeline**

First install the [Environment Script Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin)

Then configure as the image bellow

[image]

[Enviroment Script Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin)

In the image I get the version from the build.xml file, the "-o" arg in egrep (also works with grep) is to return only the part I want and not the entire line, the rest is pure regex to match the number version with . (dot), something like

***1.3.13***

**Solution WITH pipeline**

Just adjust the grep in the image for yout need's

```
def versionPrefix =  sh(script: 'grep -o (?<=<VersionPrefix>).*(?=</VersionPrefix>) ./src/project.csproj')
```

Comment: Beware that this command as is will return null, it should be: def version = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '.....')

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Groovy library called ["XmlSlurper"](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) which could be helfpul for you.

It was not allowed in Jenkins pipelines but [that issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33024) was resolved some time ago! Someone tried to do similar things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603619/extract-pom-version-in-a-jenkins-pipeline).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been answered, but if anyone else requires this behaviour and `grep -o` doesn't work, then the following command can work:

```
def versionPrefix = sh([returnStdout: true, script: 'sed -n "s/.*<VersionPrefix>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/VersionPrefix>.*/\\1/p" ./src/project.csproj'])
```

This is because - at least some - grep variants don't support lookaheads/lookbehinds.