# Jenkinsfile and POM version

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After we fetch POM model like described in Krzysztof Krasoń's answer in [extract pom version in a jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603619/extract-pom-version-in-a-jenkins-pipeline). Call to pom.version returns the fully qualified name of the artifact and not just the version.

For example

```
@NonCPS
def version() {
    pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
    pom.version
}
```

for

```
<groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

will produce

```
com.test.app:app:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Is there a way to return just the version part from returned *Model* without doing any String manipulation?

Comment: `pom.version` should return `1.0-SNAPSHOT`. Are you sure you are using it right? Put the full context so we can help you.

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko I would expect to get `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and not `1.0-SNAPSHOT`...

Comment: @khmarbaise just a typo. It will return what you specified in `<version>` tag.

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko Thanks for clearing up. That was my assumption..

Comment: @Vitalii Vitrenko What else would you need? I can't disclosure everything due to company policies. edit: I've put complete version of function we tried to use to extract version from the pom file.

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko Ok, so I've figured it out (partially). If I remove NonCPS annotation it would work as expected, with the annotation present what is being returned is an instance of the Model class (I'm not sure why in this case, so if anyone could explain?). I had that class present due to testing different approaches, of which one had non-serializable instance so I had to put the annotation in use. Now if I remove it, function will return a String containing the proper version from pom file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call regular (CPS-transformed) methods, or Pipeline steps inside `@NonCPS` methods because they requires CPS-transformation.
See more in [README.md](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md).