# Jenkins pipeline and Gradle project, how can I get the GAV properties to deploy the artifact with Jenkins Nexus Plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have recently switched from Maven to Gradle. So far my Jenkins declarative pipelines included a stage where we generated the packaged artifact and published it to Nexus:

```
  pipeline {
    ...
    stages {
      stage ('Build Stage') {
        steps {
          ...
          sh "mvn clean deploy"
          ...
        }
      }
```

This way we were using our build tool (Maven) to deploy the artifact using one of its plugins (maven deploy plugin). With [Nexus Jenkins Plugin](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2016/09/14/introducing-the-nexus-jenkins-plugin/) we can decouple these functionalities which makes sense to me: Gradle is in charge of building, testing and packaging the artifact and the Jenkins Nexus Plugin will upload it to Nexus.

The point is, following [Jenkins Nexus Plugin documentation](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/227256688-How-do-I-configure-the-Nexus-Jenkins-Plugin) I have to use a step like the following:

```
nexusPublisher nexusInstanceId: 'localNexus', nexusRepositoryId: 'releases', packages: [[$class: 'MavenPackage', mavenAssetList: [[classifier: '', extension: '', filePath: 'buildmavenCoordinate: [artifactId: 'myproject'/lib/myproject-1.0.0.jar']], , groupId: 'com.codependent.myproject', packaging: 'jar', version: '1.0.0']]]
```

Since I want to produce a resusable pipeline, I don't want to hardcode the following properties in the step:

1. groupId
2. artifactId
3. packaging
4. version

If I were working with Maven I would use the [readMavenPom step from the Pipeline Utility steps plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603619/extract-pom-version-in-a-jenkins-pipeline) to pass them to the nexusPublisher step:

```
def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
...
nexusPublisher ... mavenCoordinate: [artifactId: pom.artifactId
...
```

My problem is how to get those four parameters from Gradle configuration in the pipeline.

Suppose my build.gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

group = 'com.codependent.myproject'
version = '1.0.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Groovy in your pipeline? Gradle don't provide native support for parsing POM files. I recommend you to use XmlSlurper in Groovy.

If your pipeline is in Groovy you can read these properties with Gradle with this code:

```
def pom = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File('pom.xml'))
def version = pom.version
def artifactId = pom.artifactId
def groupId = pom.groupId
```

If you want, you can check this values directly printing variables:

```
println 'my pom version ' + pom.version
println 'my pom version ' + pom.artifactId
println 'my pom version ' + pom.groupId
```

More info about XmlSlurper: [Official page of XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html)

**EDIT:**

If you don't have pom file and you have build.gradle file, I recommend you to read this post:

[how to read a properties files and use the values in project gradle script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101589/how-to-read-a-properties-files-and-use-the-values-in-project-gradle-script)

Comment: The point is I don't have a pom.xml anymore but the build.gradle file...

Comment: In this case, probably this post can help you: [how to read a properties files and use the values in project gradle script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101589/how-to-read-a-properties-files-and-use-the-values-in-project-gradle-script)