# jenkins get environment variable pom properties nulls

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, environment-variables, pom.xml

In my jenkins project, in the configuration 'post-build actions', I try to use the plugin 'perfom subversion tagging on successful build' to realize tag automatic after build successful.

I use the environment variable {POM_VERSION} to get POM parameters, but it doesn't work.

Actually, all properties in pom.xml, like groupID, artifactID don't work. It shows that the result after getting is always null.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry I misread the first time. The maven properties are only accessible from the maven runtime. They are not directly available as environment variables for Jenkins. You will need to find a way to export these properties from maven and then import on jenkins. Take a looks here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35184962/3656963

Comment: I have read the page you recommend. I can get the version when I use the command in the execute shell, and echo it, but in the plugin "perform subversion tagging on successful build", it still shows null.