# How i can get the pom version in jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pom.xml, jenkins-pipeline

I want to get the pom version in one of my stage.For this i have this pipeline script. I have Pipeline **Utility Steps plugin installed**.

```
stage ('Publish Stage') {
            steps {
                 pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
                 echo pom.version
            }
        }
```

I am getting error with this, can anybody tell what mistake am i doing?

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: rg.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 24: Expected a step @ line 24, column 17.
                   pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'

Comment: Please add this information to the original post. Have a read through [ask] on guidelines on what is expected if you actually want help.

Comment: Use the env  var POM_VERSION. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48277831/1531945 gives an example how to use it in declarative pipeline

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign to a groovy variable in a declarative pipeline like that. You can only run steps in the `steps{}` block. If you wrap this in a `script{}` block, it will work. Take care not to declare the variable locally if you need it available elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Writing steps{} block and wrapping it inside script{} would work but in my case, I just used the variable through the environment.

```
   stage('Read Pom Version'){
       pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
       env.POM_VERSION = pom.version

       sh '''#!/bin/bash -xe
           echo $POM_VERSION
       '''.stripIndent()
    }
```

Let say the version inside my pom is 1.0.0. Above jenkins stage prints following:

```
    1.0.0
    echo 1.0.0
```

Comment: But that's code for scripted pipelines, not declarative.

Comment: Voting up, as the snippet to get pom version worked for me.