# Access a Java variable from Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am trying to find out if I could get the value of a variable declared inside a Java program or maven-plugin and store it in a Jenkins environment variable.

This is because the Jenkins file has to create a new git branch from dev and call it `Release-9.0.86` for example but the version number is inside a `pom.xml`.

I have already written a maven-plugin that retrieves the version from the `pom.xml` an writes it into another XML file, but I need to know if I could send the version to Jenkins to handle it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Project Version from Maven POM in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893503/getting-project-version-from-maven-pom-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps create a properties file instead of a xml file with the needed information. Example contents of created `branch-name.properties` file:

```
NEW_BRANCH_NAME=Release-9.0.86
```

Then you can add a **build step** "Inject environment variables" after the one that produces the properties file, and configure that to read the properties file you just created.

```
Properties File Path: branch-name.properties
```

After that you can use the environment variables as usual in the jenkins build, for example a "Execute shell" **build step** that creates the branch:

```sh
git branch ${NEW_BRANCH_NAME}
```

To then push the newly created branch you could add a "Git Publisher" **post-build action**.

```
Branch to push: ${NEW_BRANCH_NAME}
```

Please note that it might be useful to configure Git Publisher to "Push Only If Build Succeeds" i.e. branch will not be created if the build fails for any reason.