# <td> value is not returned using HtmlUnit

Tags: xpath, htmlunit

When i tried using the below code...the td tag is returned and not the value of the td tag.

```
List<?> byXPath = page2.getByXPath("//tr[@class='metadata odd']/td");
System.out.println(byXPath.get(0).toString());
```

For ex:If the tag is

```
<td class='metadata odd'>Arun</td>
```

The result was

```
<td class='metadata odd'>
```

.... I need the result to be Arun. Kindly help

Comment: For ex:If the tag is     <td class='metadata odd'>Arun</td>
The result was  <td class='metadata odd'>.... I need the result to be Arun. Kindly help

Comment: The path ending in "/" is invalid XPath syntax: nothing should be returned except an error message.

Comment: @Michael: It was a mistake...I edittted my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is actually the string representation of the text child node of the `td` tag, not the string representation of the `td` element itself, which you are requesting at the moment. 
Use a slightly different XPath expression to reference the text child node directly, like this:

```
List<?> byXPath = page2.getByXPath("//tr[@class='metadata odd']/td/text()");
DomText textNode = (DomText)(byXPath.get(0));
System.out.println(textNode.toString());
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033955/xpath-select-text-node).

Comment: There is no method like getFirstChild in get(0)

Comment: Value is there. When i debug the code and look for the values, the original value is present in inherited->data_, but not sure how to get that value from the data_ parameter

Comment: class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomText
This is the class returned. But unable to convert this to DOMMode...Sorry for making this a lengthy chat. But i am struggling past 2 hrs...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DomText domText = (DomText) form.getFirstByXPath("//tr[@class='metadata odd']/td/text()");
System.out.println(domText.getTextContent());
```

**Edit:**

If you want to get all the elements then just get them using `getByXPath` instead of `getFirstByXPath`. Then iterate over the returned List (it wasn't necessary in your question, so I didn't add that).

Comment: Wow...Got it...
But how can i loop to the next td element?

Comment: If i give getByXPath instead of getFirstByXPath it throws an error. the above comment by nyarlathotep
 worked. Thanks all :)

Comment: Yeap, but that answer is just giving you the first element. My answer is the same but less wordy :P As I told you in the answer, you have to iterate over the `LIST` that returns getByXPath.