# how to get the xpath for this element

Tags: html, xpath

I have this html element

```
<li>
   <em>Features</em><br>
   Full Options, Fully Auto, Fully Loaded, Power Locks, Power Steering, Airbag: Driver, Airbag: Passenger, Airbag: Side, Alarm, Power Windows, Rear Window Wiper, Anti-Lock Brakes, Power Seats, CD Changer, CD Player, A/C: Front, A/C: Rear, Navigation System,
</li>
```

I want to take the text inside the `li`.

Please note that I can reach the li but i don't know how to get the text inside it

I tried this:

```
.//ul/li[3]/text()
```

and this

```
.//ul/li[3]/br/text()
```

and this:

```
.//ul/li[3]/br[1]text()
```

but i got empty result.

Comment: is that workf or you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

It is

```
string(.//ul/li[3])
```

I also found a better solution which is

```
.//ul/li[3]/text()[last()]
```

Answer (score 2):

try this to get text from li

```
.//ul/li[3][text()]
```

for tha you have to dolike this

```
.//ul/li[3][text()[0]] -- select first text node
.//ul/li[3][text()[1]] -- select second text node
```

Comment: I got the whole test with the `em`, i don't want to extract the `em`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - i m not expert but you can try my update for tha t

Comment: the same , i got the whole node

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - you can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033955/xpath-select-text-node

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli = <div>text1<span>text2</span>text3</div> as I said, it is an array, so div/node()[0] == div/text()[0] == text1 node, and div/node()[1] == span node, and div/node()[2] == div/text()[1] == text3 node - you would have to concatenate them yourself (by hand or with a helper function that accepts an array).

Comment: I tried really but still the same empty result, i dubug the program and  i can see that the empty result

Comment: I found the solution , check my answer, +1 to u