# How to get element that have same parent and n th different position by xpath

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath

I'm using `selenium-webdriver` and want to get `Text` value by using `Keyword` as a start point.

```
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr><td><font>Keyword</font></td></tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr><td>Text</td></tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
```

I can get `Keyword` element like this `driver.find_element(:xpath, "//tr/td/font[text()='Keyword']")`, but I have no idea how to get `Text` element from that `Keyword`.

`Text` is always different and the Number of `tr` elements are undefined. But between `Keyword` and `Text` there are always two `tr` elements.

How can I get the value by using `xpath`?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033955/xpath-select-text-node) helps?

Comment: Not sure I'd even try to do that with XPath, I'd just walk the tree from the keyword node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath should get you the node you want:

```
//tr/td/font[contains(text(), 'Keyword')]/../../following-sibling::tr[3]/td
```