# how do i get value with xsl:value-of?

Tags: xml, xslt

if  i have an xml file like this:

```
<metallo id='1'> argento
    <simbolo> Ag </simbolo>
    <etimologia>dal latino:  Argentum</etimologia>
    <tipo comune='no'>
        <definizione> numero atomico 47 </definizione>
        <definizione informale='s'> L'argento è un metallo di transizione tenero, bianco e lucido; l'argento è il migliore ... </definizione>
   </tipo>
```

How do i get only "argento"? If i use:

```
<xsl:value-of select = "metallo"/>
```

i will get everything:

```
argentoAgdal latino: Argentumnumero atomico 47L'argento è un metallo di transizione tenero, bianco e lucido; l'argento è il migliore ...
```

I could include "argento" in  but this is a text from a test and i think i can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<xsl:value-of select = "metallo/text()[1]"/>
```

[XPath: select text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033955/xpath-select-text-node)