# How can I point to an element that doesn't contain any HTML tag?

Tags: xpath

I have the following HTML code:

```
<html>

<span class='whatever'>

  <div @id='xyz'>
    "text1"
    "text2"   <=== I am trying to extract this text
  </div>
</span>
</html>
```

Is it possible to write an xpath that points to the node that is text2? If yes, then I can extract via .text (python).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPath: select text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033955/xpath-select-text-node)

Comment: Besides perhaps you should include the[Python] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract complete `text` with `//div[@id='xyz']/text()` XPath and then get required text with

```
text.split('\n')[-1]
```

Comment: I've been using this method but was wondering if there is a better method. Looks like there isn't. One thing I want to add is that adding `/text()` at the end isn't a good method because whenever we try to fetch this element via selenium, it will lead to an error because selenium only allows grabbing HTML elements. But I realize that I didn't mention Selenium anywhere in my question so I guess we can leave this as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on what type of parser you are using for your html. Your html parser would provide you with something like a inner html or inner text node get module. You can use that and if you only want text2 you can use regular expressions or something other to filter the text out.

There is another method that if html is also written by you. Then you can enclose the text2 with span tag and directly get it.